# when click on 1 then google map not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

[Click herer For JS-FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hLd5W/23/)

first of all i put the google map on the top, its showing well, but when i click on 1 then open det1 and in the det 1 div google map is not showing well i think its jquery conflation error.  please help, thanks in advance.

here is jquery code:

```
jQuery('a[id^="prod"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
    var previs = $('div.product-detail:visible');
    $('div.product-detail').hide();
    if (previs.is($('.det' + id))) {
        $('.det' + id).hide()
    }
    else
    {
        $('.det' + id).show();
    }

    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: Man... I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to do.... Can you explain yourself clearer?

Comment: @LcSalazar you see JS-Fiddle LInk?

Comment: when i click on link 1... then open a det1 div then you will see google map, its not showing well..  i think its jquery conflict error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a jquery error. It's a google maps issue. Once you render a google map, if you resize it or change it's visibility, you will frequently experience visual issues like partial rendering.

So, the problem is that you are generating the map while the `iframe` is still hidden, so when you show it, the map will have visual issues. Instead, load the map only after showing the `iframe` and it will work:

HTML:

```
<div class="product-detail det1 cf">
    <div class="product-detail-row cf">1</div>
    <div class="directoria-map">
            <iframe src="" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
            </div><!-- directoria-map -->
    <!-- .product-detail-row -->
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery('a[id^="prod"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
    var previs = $('div.product-detail:visible');
    $('div.product-detail').hide();
    if (previs.is($('.det' + id))) {
        $('.det' + id).hide()
    }
    else
    {
        $('.det' + id).show();
        $('.det' + id).find("iframe").attr("src", "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3988.526251756596!2d-48.4791421!3d-1.4581948999999998!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x92a48e80253e4c21%3A0x2d5679c46276bb6!2sRua+dos+Mundurucus%2C+3100+-+Jurunas!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sbr!4v1402684785532");
    }

    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Try your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/hLd5W/25/

**EDIT:**

You can create a custom attribute on the tag, so you can specify a different url to each `iframe`:

HTML:

```
 <!-- .product-main -->
<div class="product-detail det1 cf">
    <div class="product-detail-row cf">1</div>
    <div class="directoria-map">
            <iframe maps-url="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3988.526251756596!2d-48.4791421!3d-1.4581948999999998!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x92a48e80253e4c21%3A0x2d5679c46276bb6!2sRua+dos+Mundurucus%2C+3100+-+Jurunas!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sbr!4v1402684785532" src="" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
            </div><!-- directoria-map -->
    <!-- .product-detail-row -->
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery('a[id^="prod"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
    var previs = $('div.product-detail:visible');
    $('div.product-detail').hide();
    if (previs.is($('.det' + id))) {
        $('.det' + id).hide()
    }
    else
    {
        $('.det' + id).show();
        var url = $('.det' + id).find("iframe").attr("maps-url");
        $('.det' + id).find("iframe").attr("src", url);
    }

    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hLd5W/26/

Comment: But if i want in the 2 link different MAP so what can i do that?